# Android: The bottom navigation view is blocking out part of my content in my ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The problem I have is that the bottom navigation bar is blocking the bottom part of my content in the ScrollView. I have tried to change the `android:layout_height` of the ScrollView to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` and it did resolve that issue, but it presented me with another. Now, the top part of my ScrollView is cut off from the display. Is there anyway to resolve both? I am using constraint layout as my parent layout of the activity.

Below is my xml code of the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/dash_bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dash_bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dash_headerImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="260dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header_background"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#40000000"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/dash_headerImg"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dash_ic_menu"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/dashboard_ic_menu"
                android:background="@drawable/dashboard_menu_background"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dash_welcomeText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome back!"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_ic_menu"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbar_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_welcomeText">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    tools:ignore="Autofill"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:hint="Search"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/dash_viewSupporter"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_headerImg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/dash_runTrackerCard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dash_calorieTrackerCard"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_viewSupporter">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:scaleX="0.7"
                        android:scaleY="0.7"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:src="@drawable/run"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Run tracker"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/dash_calorieTrackerCard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dash_runTrackerCard"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_viewSupporter">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:scaleX="0.7"
                        android:scaleY="0.7"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:src="@drawable/calorie_tracker"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Calorie tracker"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/dash_meditationCard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dash_dietCard"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_runTrackerCard">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:scaleX="0.7"
                        android:scaleY="0.7"
                        android:src="@drawable/yoga" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Meditation"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/dash_dietCard"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dash_meditationCard"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_calorieTrackerCard">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:scaleX="0.7"
                        android:scaleY="0.7"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:src="@drawable/diet"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Diet"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dash_fitnessView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dash_meditationCard"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/banner_background_light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dash_fitnessBannerLayout"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/banner_background"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dash_fitnessViewAllText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="View all" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:text="Fitness LifeStyle"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="#011a27"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Embark on your fitness journey now" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="From: bornfitness.com" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/dash_fitnessRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dash_fitnessBannerLayout"
                    android:background="#fcfdfe" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/dash_fitnessProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dash_fitnessBannerLayout"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot of my design view of the activity:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `android:layout_height="0dp"` in Scrollview.

And Please use NestedScrollView if you have Recyclerview inside Scoll

your Scrollview like this :

```
  <ScrollView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dash_bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp">
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Noted about NestedScrollView.